# Rails: Using groupdate & chartkick to create a cumulative user graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using groupdate and chartkick to try and display a graph showing the growth (and fall) of our user base over time.

Using the following it works fine in a column chart, but goes haywire in a line chart:

```
sum=0
User.group_by_day(:created_at).count.map { |x,y| { x => (sum += y)} }.reduce({}, :merge)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or is there a better way to get this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Martin's answer was close, but I ended up using:

```
User.group_by_week(:created_at).order("week asc").count.map { |x,y| { x => (sum += y)} }.reduce({}, :merge)
```

To get weekly - notice the order("week asc") - it's what fixed it...

Answer (score 13):

It's because you need to sort before you do the cumulative sum.

Try this:

```
sum=0
User.group_by_day(:created_at).count.to_a.sort{|x,y| x[0] <=> y[0]}.map { |x,y| { x => (sum += y)} }.reduce({}, :merge)
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually ended up using User.group_by_week(:created_at).order("week asc").count.map { |x,y| { x => (sum += y)} }.reduce({}, :merge) as didn't need the granularity of daily

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

one-liner:

```rb
User.group_by_day(:created_at).count.each_with_object({}) { |acc, (key, value)| acc[key] = ((acc.values.last || 0) + value); acc }
```

prettified with prettier's ruby plugin:

```rb
User
  .group_by_day(:created_at)
  .count
  .each_with_object({}) do |acc, (key, value)|
    acc[key] = ((acc.values.last || 0) + value)
  end
```